# Ruby on rails NoMethodError in custom controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, associations, partial-views, form-for

Maybe someone could tell me how to create or correctly pass `params` from partial `form_for` to custom controller? Here is what i got so far:

Basically there are two classes: **Scribbles** (polymorphic - connected to local feeds) and **local feeds**. Trough command line, I can create scribbles, assign them to local feeds and display them in html. But creating them in trough different controller seems to be a rather tricky task. Any help would be appreciated.

**Scribble.rb**

```
class Scribble < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :post, :comments_attributes, :user_id, :posted_by, :localfeed_attributes
  belongs_to :scribbled, :polymorphic => true

  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

**localfeed.rb**

```
class Localfeed < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :scribble_id, :location_id, :localfeed_id, :scribble_attributes

  belongs_to :location
  has_many :scribbles, :as => :scribbled
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :scribbles
  validates :city, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

Here is the error

```
NoMethodError in LocalfeedsController#newlocalscribble

undefined method `scribbles' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: c:/workspace/uu2

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/localfeeds_controller.rb:80:in `newlocalscribble'
```

**localfeeds/show.erb.html**

```
<% @newlocalscribble = @localfeed.scribbles.new %>
<%=render :partial => 'newlocalscribble.html.erb', :locals => {:newlocalscribble => @newlocalscribble, :localfeed => @localfeed}%>
```

**localfeeds/_newlocalscribble.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @newlocalscribble, :remote => true, :url => url_for(:controller => 'localfeeds', :action => 'newlocalscribble') do |f| %>
<div class="">
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :post,:rows=>3,:placeholder=>"What's on your mind,#{current_user.full_name}?", :class=>"sribble-status-text" %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :localfeed, :value => @localfeed.id%>
    </div>
    <div class="sribble-status-actions" id="newlocalscribble">
        <%= f.submit "Share",:class=>"btn btn-info" %>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**localfeeds_controller.rb**

```
def newlocalscribble
  @localfeed = Localfeed.find_by_id(params[:localfeed])
  @user = current_user
  @newlocalscribble = @localfeed.scribbles.create(params[:localscribble])
  #@localscribble.scribbled = @user
  #@localscribble.scribbled = @localfeed
end

def new
  @localfeed = Localfeed.new
  @feed = Localfeed.find_by_id(params[:localfeed])
  @newlocalscribble = @feed.scribbles.new
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :localfeeds do
  resource :scribbles
  collection do
    post 'localscribble', :action => :newlocalscribble
  end
end
```

**Variables passed**.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"1+/Qu/o4EeEbpiL/g07XFa3756IQDo6ldmKH196EkSQ=",
 "scribble"=>{"post"=>"hfdfs",
 "localfeed"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Share"}
```

Comment: Which line is number 80 in the localfeeds controller? It looks like one of these two lines is failing because the localfeed or the feed object is nil: `@newlocalscribble = @localfeed.scribbles.create(params[:localscribble])` `@newlocalscribble = @feed.scribbles.new`

Comment: @newlocalscribble = @localfeed.scribbles.create(params[:localscribble]) this one is failing

Answer (score 0):

most likely your variable `params[:localfeed]` is not set right. It is either `nil` or the value that came in is not in the database.

Comment: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"1+/Qu/o4EeEbpiL/g07XFa3756IQDo6ldmKH196EkSQ=",
 "scribble"=>{"post"=>"hfdfs",
 "localfeed"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Share"}

Comment: yes you are right, its not passing the params, played around with it, Got it to pass the right stuff, but now i get Can't mass-assign protected attributes: localfeed . Updated original to show the models as well. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved It by passing the :locals => {:scribble => @scribble, :localfeed => @localfeed} to pass the right feed ID params to partial, and deleted the hidden field which created a duplicate and cause mass assignment error

Thank you Guys